# Java Methods - How to implement a loop using methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm currently working on an assignment for my Intro to Java Course. I've completed majority of the assignment: refactor a Rock, Paper, Scissor game I created in the past but using methods.  When my code is executed; it prints a welcome message, prompts for user input and then prints the user's choice and the CPU's choice.
My question: How do i implement a while loop into my methods so that after the code is executed it will run a best 2/3 games?

To my understanding, I know that I must use a loop in each method. Where the input from the user will be different and the cpu will generate another random move.

*Note: I'm not asking for a direct solution but for something conceptual as to what would be a good approach to this problem.

Below is my code:

```
package rpsmethods;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RPSMethods {

    public static void displayOpeningMessage() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to RPS Game 2.0!");
    }

    public static int getUserMove() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Select scissors (0), rock (1), or scissors (2): ");
        int choice = 0;
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                choice = input.nextInt();
                switch (choice) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("You chose scissor!");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("You chose rock!");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("You chose paper!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Not a valid input!");
                        System.out.print("Select scissors (0), rock (1), or scissors (2): ");
                        choice = input.nextInt();
                    }
            }
         return choice;
    }

    public static int getCPUMove() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int CPUMove = rnd.nextInt(3);
        switch (CPUMove) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("CPU chose scissor!");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("CPU chose rock!");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("CPU chose paper!");
                break;
        }
        return CPUMove;
    }

    public static void determineWinner(int user, int cpu) {
        //User win scenarios
        if (user == 0 && cpu == 2) {
            System.out.println("You win, Scissors beat Paper!");
        } else if (user == 1 && cpu == 0) {
            System.out.println("You win, Rock beats Scissors!");
        } else if (user == 2 && cpu == 1) {
            System.out.println("You win, Paper beats Rock!");
        }
        //Cpu win scenarios
        if (user == 0 && cpu == 1) {
            System.out.println("You lose, Rock beats Scissors!");
        } else if (user == 1 && cpu == 2) {
            System.out.println("You lose, Paper beats Rock!");
        } else if (user == 2 && cpu == 0) {
            System.out.println("You lose, Scissor beats Paper!");
        }
        //Draw scenarios
        if (user == 0 && cpu == 0) {
            System.out.println("You and CPU chose Scissor, it's a draw!");
        } else if (user == 1 && cpu == 1) {
            System.out.println("You and CPU chose Rock, it's a draw!");
        } else if (user == 2 && cpu == 2) {
            System.out.println("You and CPU chose Paper, it's a draw!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayOpeningMessage();
        int userWinner = getUserMove();
        int CpuWinner = getCPUMove();
        determineWinner(userWinner, CpuWinner);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define two static variables to check the final winner in your
 class:

```
static int cpuScore = 0;  
static int humanScore = 0;
```

Then, you can set a value for that variables inside determineWinner like this:

```
if (CPU wins) 
  cpuScore++
else 
  humanScore++;
```

Then you can put your top level steps inside a loop like this:

```
while (cpuScore < 2 && humanScore < 2) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leonardo! I was able to figure it out.  I appreciate your help!